# How can I extract the image/3d model assets from a Unity compiled APK file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I've downloaded the APK file for a game called [Subway Surfers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiloo.subwaysurf) I'm also trying to "extract" the assets from the game (images, 3D models, etc). I've decompiled it using
[APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) I'm trying to extract the images from the decompiled source from [my research](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) I think that these images are stored within [these bundle files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orpiw.png).

I've also learned that there is a tool called [UTinyRipper](https://github.com/mafaca/UtinyRipper) but every time I try to throw in these bundle files, the whole extracted folder entirely or even the .assets files [(which have strange .split(0, 1, 2, etc) file extensions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqv0F.png) [I've gotten nothing at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZAI2.png) or [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvBM9.png). I think the answer may be something completely different.

To rephrase; how can I extract the image/3d model assets from a Unity compiled APK file?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to... ahem... "borrow" someone else's assets? I'd recommend contacting the owner and just asking to use/purchase them.